# Multiple array_agg in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

[image]

I wanted to group information in arrays based on the first two variables and thats what I did

[image]

```
WITH sample as (
SELECT 1023 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'chop' as type,
'c1023' as id_cus, 'julian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'julian@gmail.com' as    mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1023 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'ext' as type,
'c1023' as id_cus, 'julian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'julian@gmail.com' as    mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'inegi' as    origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'ext' as type,
'in-2020' as id_cus, 'lucian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'lucian@gmail.com' as  mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'inegi' as    origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'ext' as type,
'in-2020' as id_cus, 'lucian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'lucian@gmail.com' as  mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'int' as type,
'c1021' as id_cus, 'lucian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'lucian@gmail.com' as    mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'int' as type,
'c1021' as id_cus, 'lucas' as name, '202342' as phone, 'lucas@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'type' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '202112' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'chop' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '202112' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'rad' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '202112' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'uls' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '123123' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
)
SELECT id,valuation,ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(origin,date_lead,type,id_cus,name,phone,mail)) as lead 
FROM sample
GROUP BY id,valuation
```

The problem here is that I noticed that I have a lot of repeteated values in the last three variables (name,phone and mail).
I would like to group them as well but I am not sure how to do that. I noticed that I can't create an additional array_agg instide of the first one.

I am looking to get something like this:

[image]

There is anyway to do something like this? WHat would you do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap another SELECT ... GROUP BY around the original query like:

```sql
WITH sample as (
SELECT 1023 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'chop' as type,
'c1023' as id_cus, 'julian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'julian@gmail.com' as    mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1023 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'ext' as type,
'c1023' as id_cus, 'julian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'julian@gmail.com' as    mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'inegi' as    origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'ext' as type,
'in-2020' as id_cus, 'lucian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'lucian@gmail.com' as  mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'inegi' as    origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'ext' as type,
'in-2020' as id_cus, 'lucian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'lucian@gmail.com' as  mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'int' as type,
'c1021' as id_cus, 'lucian' as name, '12345' as phone, 'lucian@gmail.com' as    mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1021 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'int' as type,
'c1021' as id_cus, 'lucas' as name, '202342' as phone, 'lucas@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'type' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '202112' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'chop' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '202112' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'rad' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '202112' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
UNION ALL
SELECT 1040 as id,10 as valuation,'tlv' as  origin, 2021-01-01 as date_lead,'uls' as type,
'c1040' as id_cus, 'julieta' as name, '123123' as phone, 'julieta@gmail.com' as mail
)
SELECT id,valuation,ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(lead,name,phone,mail)) FROM (
    SELECT id,valuation,name,phone,mail, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(origin,date_lead,type,id_cus)) as lead 
    FROM sample
    GROUP BY id,valuation,name,phone,mail
)
GROUP BY id,valuation
```

[image]